# jQuery loop over html, on change, find class, remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got multiple forms with selects on a page. For each form I want the submit button to have a class of disabled until an option is selected, at which point the button should lose the disabled class (each form must work independently of the others). I can't seem to get this working using Next or Find. Here's my code:

```
<-- FORM ONE -->

<form>
  <label for="available-countries-#variables.x#">Available Countries</label>
  <select id="available-countries-#variables.x#" class="form-control available-countries-selector">
    <option value="0">-- Select Country --</option>
    <option value="1">Australia</option>
    <option value="2">Brazil</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default disabled" role="button">Submit</a>
</form>

<-- FORM TWO -->

<form>
  <label for="available-countries-#variables.x#">Available Countries</label>
  <select id="available-countries-#variables.x#" class="form-control available-countries-selector">
    <option value="0">-- Select Country --</option>
    <option value="1">Argentina</option>
    <option value="2">France</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default disabled" role="button">Submit</a>
</form>

-- JS --

$('.available-countries-selector').change(function(){    
  if($(this).val() !== '0'){
    $(this).find('btn-default').removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).find('btn-default').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for the button in the current form. Best way to do that is using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
var isEnabled = $(this).val() !== '0';
$(this).closest("form").find('btn-default').toggleClass('disabled', !isEnabled);
```

---

How I would code it with event bubbling:

```
$(document).on("change", ".available-countries-selector", function(){  
    var isDisabled = $(this).val() === "0";
    $(this).closest("form").find('btn-default').toggleClass('disabled', isDisabled);
});
```

ideally you would set `document` to an element that is closer to the forms.

Comment: Double negatives? :) just use `$(this).closest("form").find('btn-default').toggleClass('disabled', $(this).val());`

Comment: Good use of `toggleClass` with switch value :)

Comment: and +1 for suggesting using a delegated event handler :)

Answer (score 1):

In the JS context, the `this` is the `<select>` element. Since the `btn-default` is not inside the select, it will not find it with that code.

Instead you can go to the closest form parent and find it from there:

```
$(this).closest("form").find('btn-default').removeClass('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

The submit button is not within the selector you are using so `$(this).find` will not work. However, you can use `$(this).next()` since the submit button is immediately after the select dropdown, like this:

```
$('.available-countries-selector').change(function(){    
  if($(this).val() !== '0'){
    $(this).next().removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).next().addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jukx8sp/1/)

Comment: `toggleClass` can also take a boolean as a switch, so you can shorten all this to: `$(this).next().toggleClass('disabled', $(this).val());`

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your `<button>`s with a `</a>` and your `find()` is not looking for a classname (because you've excluded the dot) nor can you *find* a sibling. Use [`next([selector])`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the next `.btn-default`:

```
$('.available-countries-selector').change(function(){    
  if($(this).val() !== '0'){
    $(this).next('.btn-default').removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).next('.btn-default').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mL9h2fof/

**UPDATE** (thanks @TrueBlueAussie)
You could use .toggleClass to make this even simpler:

```
$('.available-countries-selector').change(function(){    
  $(this).next('.btn-default').toggleClass('disabled', $(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mL9h2fof/1/

Comment: `toggleClass` can also take a boolean as a switch, so you can shorten all this to: `$(this).next('.btn-default').toggleClass('disabled', $(this).val());`